# C# WPF Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a WPF Appl. in C#. I got a `MainWindow.xaml` which contains an empty frame called MainFrame. I got four other pages called `Welcome.xaml`, `Login.xaml`, `ObjectSelection.xaml` and `Exec.xaml` . To navigate from `MainWindow` through the pages via the navigation buttons that are on the `MainWindow`, I simply can do this and call it on my buttons:

```
private void PageNav1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainFrame.Content = new Welcome();
}
```

I have buttons in that Welcome Page that need to bring you to another page, let's say to the `Login.xaml` . My approach was this:

```
private void SelectionExport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow.MainFrame.Content = new Login();
}
```

But as usual I got an error:
`CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainWindow.MainFrame'    INTEGR8`

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [here's the documentation for that error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120). Its not really related to navigation per se.

Comment: What is `MainWindow` in your Login.xaml.cs file?

Comment: I would recommend using a `ContentControl` and changing the content via binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the *instance* of the `MainWindow` class and access the `Frame` of this one:

```
private void SelectionExport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    mainWindow.MainFrame.Content = new Login();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120) says

> In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance.

For example,

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public void MyMethod() { }

    public static void MyStaticMethod() { }
}

MyClass.MyStaticMethod(); // Works
MyClass.MyMethod(); // CS0120

// You've got to do it like this

MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.MyMethod();
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, it doesn't answer the question at all.